# Disabling an annoying debugger notification in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, windows, performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Whenever I start debugging with `heap profiling` turned on in the `Diagnostics tools` in my Visual Studio 2017, I get the following notification(s):

[image: Heap profiling is enabled notification]
This is quite annoying, since I was made aware of the performance impact these debugging methods might have on my program the first 10 times I was presented with such notifications. To make things worse, the notifications do not disappear by themselves, but instead I have to close them everytime I've been debugging.

Where might I find an option to turn these things off, so I might profile the heap in peace?

**TO BE CLEAR:** I do not wish to disable heap profiling. I wish to disable the warning/notification I am presented with whenever I profile the heapiness.

Comment: I would say you should use Microsoft's feedback hub. Being aware of a performance impacting operation is important, and IMO it's just by design that this notification is displayed every time.

Comment: Does your application perform heavy allocations? Maybe this notification is caused by [one of built-in information rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mg3c.png).

Comment: @VTT A few of those looked pretty promising, but as far as I could tell, turning any of them off didn't have an effect on the notifications.

Comment: I tried different things, but still unable to reproduce it with my Visual Studio 2017 (Version 15.3.1). What is your VS version?

Comment: @Codeguard After updating to the latest available version, I'm still getting those notifications.

Comment: Sorry, still no idea how to reproduce. I do not have the message at all. You should try to create a minimal code that reproduces the problem and post here.

Answer (score 2):

Some notifications in Visual Studio 2017 have **Don't Show Again** option like this one:
[image]

If the solution to your issue still not available in the latest version of **Visual Studio 2017 15.3**. You can report this in Visual Studio 2017. Let them know to add **Don't Show Again** option in **Heap Profiling notification**.

Here are the steps on [how to report a problem with visual studio 2017](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017.md).